# Involutions in $\left[ G,\varphi \right] $.

Tags: group-theory

Set $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}\left( G\right) $ with order $2$. Consider the
semidirect product $G\rtimes \left\langle \varphi \right\rangle$. ($G$ is infinite)

Let $\left[ G,\varphi \right] =\left\langle g^{-1}g^\varphi ;g\in
G\right\rangle \trianglelefteq G.$

My question is:

> Does $\left[ G,\varphi \right] $ have involutions?

I think doesn't have!

Help!

Comment: What?? Let $G$ be the Klein four group, then $\left[ G,\varphi \right]$ is a group of order 2...

Comment: I've voted to close.  Your original question was easily seen to be false, and after I gave a counterexample, you changed the question.  You changed it without thinking it would seem, because my counterexample can easily be extended to cover this new case as well.  I am not confident you have given much thought to this question, and without any motivation, I voted to close.

Comment: your answer for finite groups was good.  
Although it didn't place before, my subject is  
really for G infinite.Sorry!

Comment: Just to follow up on Steve D's comment, you can cross the Klein four group with $\mathbb{Z}$ and just let $\phi$ be the identity on the $\mathbb{Z}$ part.  Before you edit again, consider taking $G$ to be an infinite direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: What does mean $\varphi$ let be identity on the Z part?

Comment: It means that $\phi$ stabilizes $\mathbb{Z}$, so for $(a,b) \in V\times \mathbb{Z}$, $(a,b)^\phi=(a^\phi,b)$.